# How can a nested/inner class get a variable from an outer class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have class with a nested/inner class. How to get the class variable `moduleId` within class `B`'s init method to pass it into `ExtraSuperClass`?

```
class A:
  moduleId = 1

  class B(ExtraSuperClass):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(moduleId)

  def __init__(self):
     n = self.B()
```

Comment: Class `B` is technically not a "subclass" of `A`. It's a nested/inner class.

Answer (score 0):

In example you provided you could access it like this:

```
A.moduleId
```

Also, you can't call B like that, you should do it like this:

```
self.B()
```